# MQTT communication for devices, which one is the better option for PubSub data either RabbitMQ or Azure ServiceBus for IotConnect?

Tags: iot, azure-iot-sdk, iotconnect

MQTT communication for devices, which one is the better option for PubSub data either RabbitMQ or Azure ServiceBus for IotConnect?

We have use cases for the smart device that can continue be sending data on the cloud, which option is best and cost-effective that generate large amount data with many devices without any interruption.

We want to go with Azure ServiceBus, I want to know is the best option over the RabbitMQ for IotConnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MQTT**
MQTT is the PubSub Protocol which is highly used in IoT platform to receive and send data over the cloud. Its **cost effective** too. Here are some benefits to use it.

- more efficient information distribution
- increased scalability
- a reduction in network bandwidth consumption dramatically;
- reduces update rates to seconds;
- is well suited for remote sensing and control;
- maximizes available bandwidth;
- lightweight overhead;
- uses permission-based security;
- has a robust ecosystem and is used by the oil-and-gas industry,
  Amazon.com and Facebook;
- can save development time;
- the publish/subscribe protocol collects more data with less bandwidth
  compared to polling protocols.

**Azure Service Bus**
Azure service bus provides the same solution as like MQTT. In fact in the background, it has used the MQTT protocol to manage the PubSub data. It is Microsft's tool and it's costly.

With the use of Azure Service Bus features, as it is being a Cloud-based solution it will definitely streamline the communication channel between the sender and the receiver and also makes it convenient for the user as they are more reliable and broadly available in the market space.

**Conclusion**
I as per my opinion If my purpose is to only transfer the data from sender to receiver then MQTT will be helpful. While my purpose is to beyond the send and receives the data like send notification using Azure notification hub, Manage complex data workflow, manage to the queue of data, etc. It will be suitable for large application to manage complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Service Bus doesn't support MQTT directly. [Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#protocols)

Azure IoT Hub supports MQTT. [Communicate with your IoT hub using the MQTT protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support)

It is hard to compare RabbitMQ and Azure IoT Hub, but if you want to get a ready to use IoT platform in cloud, you can choose Azure IoT Hub.